# gdal_edit not find as internal command in Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal2tiles

I am writing the geoinformation using the `gdal_edit` command using python in Jupyter notebook. Below is the syntax.

```
!gdal_edit -a_ullr -1.149576  85.247405 -92.762859  88.022318 -a_srs "+proj=Stere +datum=D_Moon_Spheroid +no_defs" Input.tif Output.tif
```

I am getting the following error after I run the above line

> ```
> 'gdal_edit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

After two days of searching on Google, I was still unable to find the answer.
Can you help me?

Below is the link for input image for which I want to add geoinformation
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KPhnJSrV7xK3oz8OgQXeDQGcKznW3G8q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does it work as `gdal_edit.py` or `python gdal_edit.py`?

Comment: In Jupyter it works as !gdal_edit

Comment: Does GDAL work generally `gdalinfo --version`? What version do you have? Notice that gdal_edit is a python script https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html and you should have file gdal_edit.py somewhere. In some environments `gdal_edit` is configured to work as an alias to `gdal_edit.py`.

Comment: I checked the version is GDAL 2.3.3, released 2018/12/14

Comment: The location of my gdal_edit.py file is unknown to me. Can you please help me locate it?

Comment: Current version is 3.5. I suggest to update first https://gdal.org/download.html#current-release.

Comment: I have upgraded the gdal version, but still is error is same.

Comment: Next acquire the gdal_edit.py script if you do not have it. It is for example in GitHub https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/scripts. Then you need to have GDAL Python bindings. You have them if you can do with Python `from osgeo import gdal`.

Answer (score 2):

If the gdal is installed in conda, then the "gdal_edit.py" is found at

```
~/.conda/envs/<conda env>/bin/gdal_edit.py
```

If we assume gdal is installed in the "space_sci" conda environment then,
"gdal_edit.py" in Jupiter notebook can be executed in one of the following ways:

```
! ~/.conda/envs/space_sci/bin/gdal_edit.py
! python ~/.conda/envs/space_sci/bin/gdal_edit.py
! gdal_edit.py


! ~/.conda/envs/space_sci/bin/gdal_edit.py -a_ullr -1.149576  85.247405 -92.762859  88.022318 -a_srs "+proj=Stere +datum=D_Moon_Spheroid +no_defs" Input.tif Output.tif
```